# Laravel - Catch php artisan commands

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-helper, laravel-environment

I've did some changes in my `config/app` to use multiple databases selected by front-end,
now I have to tell in `\Request()->header('database')` which database I want access.

It's work perfectly, the problem is: when I try to do any artisan commands my logic dies, because isn't informed the database.

So I need to inform the database in **artisan commands**, like that:

```
php artisan migrate --database=sandiego_school
php artisan migrate:rollback --database=newyork_school
```

How can I observer all commands to get the argument?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I guess you should create your own commands that overrides the commands you want to call, then in the handle method of the command you could specify the connexion you want to work on:

```
\DB::setDefaultConnection($connexion);
```

or also you can simply add header to request:

```
request()->headers->set('database', $dbname)
```

Comment: My question is how can I set this 'database' with command argument. I can't set default connection.